# Prevent XSS in Socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io, xss

How does one sanitize output through NodeJS SocketIO?

I basically have a very simple SocketIO chat application that renders messages broadcasted by the server, and I'm trying to figure out how I could prevent messages such as

```
<script>...</script>
```

or other forms of XSS to be injected in the frontend chat.

What I'm doing is basically:

```
$('#chat').append(message);
```

I've been told to escape the message on the backend (output) and not on the frontend. Is that correct? If so, how should I escape it? Any node modules?

Answer (score 1):

Escaping is something you do while outputting to the HTML, and as such nodejs and socket.io is mostly irrelevant. See the OWASP XSS Prevention cheat sheet for different contexts which require different escapings. You appear to be using jQuery. You could use jQuery encoder, or simply something like:

```
$("<div>").text(message).appendTo("#chat")
```

Comment: So XSS prevention should be done on the frontend? I've been advised that the "messages" emitted from the sockets should already be sanitized before being received by the client